# Joomla 404 After Trying to Log in as Admin

Tags: php, joomla, mamp

I am running my site using MAMP. I can reach the login page at /administator, but this 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGmiM.jpg) error gets thrown after logging in

I have tried turning off all SEF stuff to no avail. What can I do?

Note that I get re directed to /index.php when I believe it should be /administator/index.php

Comment: how did you manage to turn off SEF stuff ?

Comment: configuration.php in your document root. Turn sef, sef_rewrite, and sef_suffix to 0.